# Trying to bulk insert csv file with code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert a csv file directly from assets/temp/filename, into mysql table users_csv_import.

I am getting mysql syntax error and I cannot find it.

```
    function bulk_insert_file($filename) {

        $file_location = 'assets/temp/'.$filename;
        $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file_location."' INTO TABLE users_csv_import
        TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";

        $this->db->query($sql); 
    }
```

Getting this error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TERMINATED BY ' '' at line 2

LOAD DATA INFILE 'assets/temp/new_users_template24.csv' INTO TABLE users_csv_import TERMINATED BY ' '

Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

Line Number: 330

Comment: you have to check your query have some syntax error is $this->db->last_query() and try to execute manually and see correct the error

Comment: @saurabh2836 What's not clear? The query syntax is wrong, it's written right in the error message

Answer (score 0):

You've an error in the query syntax, you mismatched some quotes there. Should be:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file_location."' INTO TABLE users_csv_import
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```